# JAXB write arbitrary text as first line of XML file generated from stream

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I am using JAXB to marshal out objects and current my console output differs from my generated XML file:

Console:

```
<!-- My awesome comment --> 
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Cat>
    <name>Toby</name>
</Cat>
```

Generated:

```
<Cat>
    <name>Toby</name>
</Cat>
```

I expect the output in the console to match what is generated within `Cat.xml` however this is not the case.  My question is what is incorrect in my approach to generate a "correct" `Cat.xml`?
Minimum functioning program below:

```
public class CatDriver{  
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException,
            ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

        Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.setName("Toby");
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Cat.class);

        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.setProperty(
                "com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders",
                "<!-- My awesome comment"
                        + " --> \n <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
        m.marshal(cat, System.out);
        Writer w = null;
        try {
            w = new FileWriter("C:/test/Cat.xml");
            m.marshal(cat, w);

        } finally {
            try {
                w.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Cat")
class Cat {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this article: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html

It is not exactly what you need but probably it is even better approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.setName( "Toby" );
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( Cat.class );

Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE );
m.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.FALSE );

m.marshal( cat, System.out );
Writer w = null;
try
{
  w = new FileWriter( "Cat.xml" );
  w.append( "<!-- My awesome comment -->" );
  w.flush();
  m.marshal( cat, w );

}
finally
{
  try
  {
    w.close();
  }
  catch ( Exception e )
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: Example for completeness please.  Especially since there is no default constructor available.

Comment: @Woot4Moo If it is working for the console, it should work for the file, too. The only difference is that you have already used the marshaller once. So use context.createMarshaller(); a second time before writing to file. Anyway using sun specific properties seems not a good idea to me. Why don't you leave the JAXB_Fragment to false and just write out the comment directly to the filewriter?

Comment: Because JAXB exposes a way to do it.  Also removing the call to system.out did not resolve the issue.